# Magento Sql Query

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I need to generate the following with an SQL statement in magento database.But i do not exactly know, where the tables and the fields are?

Order number, SKU, Item name, Quantity, Item price, Total Line price, Cost of each item(I don't know whether this is a custom attribute or not), Total Line Cost, Order Total Cost, Shipping, Order Total Price

Comment: Why a raw SQL query ? why not using the dedicated models ?

Comment: But i need all the attributes

Comment: and ? one more time : why not using the dedicated models ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at

```
sales_flat_order
sales_flat_order_*
.....
sales_flat_order_item
```

or you could load the order and get all the info (also some of the order info are store in the db as php serialize array)

```
 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
 $items = $order->getAllItems();
 //$items->getData(); //use the getData() method to see a list of all the fields
```